# getAdapterPosition() is not found as a method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I recently uprated to Android Studio 2.3 and not the getAdapterPosition (RecyclerView) cannot be found. I saw on the web that the reason for that is the support library version. But I am not sure how to solve it still. My support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0' version is the latest possible (e.g. above 21). I don't understand why the method is not found. Any advice, please?

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/wekaSTRIPPED.jar')
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') { // Material Drawer
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
compile 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.3.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.7' // Scheduling library
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
```

Comment: getLayoutPosition() is better option to get item position. You can try to use this if you don't find solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you please check you are using this method in ViewHolder Class?

**getAdapterPostion()** is the method of **RecyclerView.ViewHolder**.

You need to make sure you are using this method inside the class extending **RecyclerView.ViewHolder**

Comment: It was that simple :D I was using it outside of the ViewHolder class. Thanks a lot for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
```

may be missing that line ???

Comment: I did try that. It was not the case. Thanks for the suggestion, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please add this dependency:
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it did not get rid of the error :/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to use buildToolsVersion 25.2.0 too, and in my case the gradle showed me and error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.2.0, 25.0.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0

To solve this I have had to add this line `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'` forcing to use this version for customtabs.

**Before:**

```
//    android support
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

**After:**

```
//    android support
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

If you have an error like this, I recommend you to add the library that shows the error with the version you want.